# Is there a way to read a raw netcdf file and tell what layer a value belongs to?

Tags: netcdf

I'm in the process of evaluating how successful a script I wrote is and kind of a quick and dirty method I've employed is looking at the first few values and last few values of a single variable and doing a few calculations with them based on the same values in another netcdf file.

I know that there are better ways to approach this but again, this is a really quick and dirty method that has worked for me so far. My question though is that by looking at the raw data through ncdump, is there a way to tell which vertical layer that data belongs to? In my example, the file has 14 layers. I"m assuming that the first few values are a part of the surface layer and the last few values are a part of the top layer, but I suspect that this assumption is wrong, at least in part.

As a follow-up question, what would then be the easiest 'proper' way to tell what layer data belongs to? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`ncview` and `NCO` are both very powerful and quick command line operators to view data inside a netcdf file.

ncview: http://meteora.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncview_home_page.html

NCO: http://nco.sourceforge.net/

You can easily show variables over all layers for example with

```
ncks -d layer,0,13 some_infile.nc
```

Answer (score 0):

ncdump dumps the data with the last dimension varying fastest (http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf/CDL-Syntax.html) so if 'layer' is the slowest/first dimension, the earlier values are all in the first layer, while the last few values are in the last layer.

As to whether the first layer is the top or bottom layer, you'd have to look to the 'layer' dimension and its data.